# @Cacheable not working as expected for loading content on startup

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I have this utility method to load content for my web application

```
@Cacheable(value="dataStrore" )
public MarketJson retrieveMarketJson(DataRequest request) throws Exception{     
            try {
```

.....

The caching works fine when this in invoked via normal web requests but the first request does take a long time as this involves lot of processing.

So I added a component where I try to load this at server startup.

```
@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
public void contextRefreshedEvent() {
  //call retrieveMarketJson method for all possible requests  
}
```

This shows fine to work in log files but when the web requests come in, it appears the caching has not happened and it loads and cached at that point and than going forward works fine.

I am using EHCache.

Comment: Can you share DataRequest class code?

Comment: Are the two methods you showed in the same class?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. Method `initialize()` is going to run on application initialization.

```
@Component
public class InitializeCachedData {

    @Autowired
    private SampleService sampleService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        // Call retrieveMarketJson method for all possible requests
        sampleService.callMethod();
    }
}
```

UPDATE

You can try modify your code using `ContextRefreshedEvent` in order to avoid running for root context.

```
@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
public void contextRefreshedEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent e) {
    if (e.getApplicationContext().getParent() != null) {
        //call retrieveMarketJson method for all possible requests  
    }
}
```

Comment: When the PostConstruct is executing, will the tomcat hold on service client requests?

Comment: As it is documented, _The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed after dependency injection is done to perform any initialization_. Tomcat will hold for method to complete its job, before application initialization continues.

Comment: This works fine but again it does not help in caching, perhaps the caching beans are not initialize or ready to store cache, how can i make it run as last thing in application start up?

Comment: Cache configuration is defined in a `@Configuration` class?

Comment: i just do @EnableCaching

Comment: Updated my answer with a modification to your initial code. I tried in a sample project and it seems to work fine. Maybe you can run your code using some breakpoints in order to see exactly what it is happening.

Comment: I should be running for root content, not avoiding it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153897/discussion-between-lzagkaretos-and-mark1234).